# Some pyautogui code is unreachable ,How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

**code**

```
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard as kb

def Screenshot():
  im = pg.screenshot(region=(0, 0, 100, 100))
  im.show()
  im.save("screenshot.png")

while True:
  if kb.is_pressed("a"):
     Screenshot()
```

Vscode Editor said im.show() and im.save("screenshot.png") are unreachable.
but when I run program works fine , still can take screenshot , show image ,and save image.
can someone tell me why?
how can I fix unreachable warning in editor?

Comment: what editor are you using?

Comment: @depperm Vscode

Comment: this is may be because of indent is 2 spaces change it to 4 spaces and it will work. [**WELL YOU NEED TO REFORMAT YOUR CODE AFTER THAT.**]